# Is there client side code that can pull AD information from the current user?

Tags: php, javascript, active-directory

I have a PHP website on a Ubuntu web server and the users that will be accessing the website will be on Windows PCs.  I am aware that Unix cannot pull Active Directory information from the current user through PHP, but I was curious if there is any client side code that can pull the information and then passed into a PHP Variable.  I am unable to host the site on a Windows Server with IIS or else this job would be much simpler using PHP $_SERVER Variables.

Using JScript or any other client-side code, can I make requests that would be similar to the PHP $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] or $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']?  All I need is to pull the username of the current user, computer name, or, even better, Organizational Unit.

I want to be able to use this information for Windows Authentication into PHP Based Sites that are not on a server with IIS.

Comment: Why wouldn't PHP be able to pull Active Directory information for the user? I don't think ldap_bind is OS specific.

Comment: I can pull Active Directory information without an issue... but not from the current user visiting the site using PHP without IIS.

Comment: Can't use Apache's mod_authnz_ldap?

Comment: Researching that right now. Thanks

Comment: Also -- on intranet (note, not localhost) $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] contains the computer\user or domain\user for an authenticated user -- although, my preference is to force them to log in to the application so that I can verify their password against AD.